# How do I find point coordinates knowing only distance to another point?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, coordinates

For the beginning we have two points with coordinates x, y, z: start(0, 0, 0) and randomly generated r(x, y, z) where x, y, z are random integers from 0 to 100.

There is a function (already written by me) that calculates distance between start point and r.

I need to write another function that takes only distance as an argument. We need to call the first function using different coordinates inside start point (to change distance between points) until we find the coordinates of r (that is distance should be equal to 0).

What is the best algorithm in this case?

My first part of the code including function that calculates distance:

```
const r = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    r.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1); // Generating random r point
}

const s = [0, 0, 0];
let distance;

function calculateDistance(random, myPoint) {
    distance = Math.abs(
                    Math.floor(
                        Math.sqrt(
                            Math.pow((random[0] - myPoint[0]), 2) +
                            Math.pow((random[1] - myPoint[1]), 2) + 
                            Math.pow((random[2] - myPoint[2]), 2)
                        )
                    )
                    );
    return distance;
}
```

Next I did the following:

```
function searchPoint(distance) {
    let min = 173,   // biggest possible distance if r(100, 100, 100)
        tempArr = [],
        closePoints = [],
        prev;

    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        while (s[i] < 100) {  // For x, y, z of start point I go through every possible value
            prev = min; // Keep track on previos min value                              
            if (min > distance) {
                min = distance;
            }
    
            if (prev < distance) { // If the distance increases it means we're drifting away from needed coordinates
                break;
            }

            tempArr.push({distance, point: s[i]});  // Here I save pairs distance-coordinate
            s[i]++;
            distance = calculateDistance(r, s);
        }
        closePoints.push(tempArr.filter(obj => obj.distance === min)); // For each of 3 coordinates I leave only minimal values, but the thing is there are several of them
        tempArr = [];
        min = 173;
    }

    let mappedPoints = closePoints.map(arr => {
        let mid = Math.floor((arr.length - 1) / 2); // So as a solution I try to pick up middle element from an array of points close to the needed one (which works most of the time BUT*)
        return arr[mid];
    });
    console.log(mappedPoints);
    mappedPoints.forEach((obj, i) => s[i] = obj.point); 

    console.log(s);
    console.log(calculateDistance(r, s));

    if (calculateDistance(r, s) === 0) {            // We check up on the distance and it's only logical that if it's equal to 0 - we found the point
        console.log('Point was found!!!');
    }
```

- But! In boundary values (let's say <14 and >86), the needed point in the closePoints array won't be IN THE MIDDLE (for example, 2/5/94/98)
  In addition, there may be more than one such point - in cases like [3, 45, 93].
  So this is the part where I got stuck...

Comment: How is it possible to determine the point given only the distance from the origin? That's the graph of a circle, not a point.

Comment: What algorithms have you attempted? You should include all relevant functions in your post, preferably as a snippet.

Comment: a graph of a ball

Comment: I think there could be an interesting question here, but the problem setup is not clear. Could you add an example or illustration?

Comment: guys I updated the question, take a look please

Comment: Which location is 100km from the Eiffel Tower?

Answer (score 1):

I was curious as for performance for calculating all points (in 3d space of integers) that match (the naive algorithm).

```js
function distance_squared(x, y, z) {
  return x * x + y * y + z * z;
}

var r_squared = 9230
for (var x = 0; x <= 100; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y <= 100; y++) {
    for (var z = 0; z <= 100; z++) {
      if (distance_squared(x, y, z) == r_squared) {
        console.log(x, y, z)
      }
    }
  }
}

// console.log(distance_squared(79,42,35))
```

Now combined with a recent [question about isometric projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73559567/reverse-isometric-projection-in-javascript/73560177) of 3D coordinates, gives:

```js
function Coords_3D_To_2D(x, y, z) {
  return {
    w: ((x - y) * (Math.sqrt(3) / 2)),
    h: (((-x - y) / 2) - z)
  }
}

function distance_squared(x, y, z) {
  return x * x + y * y + z * z;
}


function Projectile(x, y, speed, direction, duration) {
  Object.assign(this, {
    x,
    y,
    speed,
    direction,
    duration
  });
  this.draw = ctx => {
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 3.75, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fill();
  }
  this.update = ctx => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    this.x += Math.cos(this.direction) * this.speed;
    this.y += Math.sin(this.direction) * this.speed;
    this.draw(ctx);
    this.duration--;
  }
  this.isDone = () => this.duration <= 0;
}



const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var x0 = canvas.width / 2
var y0 = canvas.height / 2;
var projectileArray = []


;
(function update() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < projectileArray.length; i++) {
    let bullet = projectileArray[i];
    bullet.update(ctx)
  }
  projectileArray = projectileArray.filter(bullet => !bullet.isDone());



  requestAnimationFrame(update);
})();

document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (event.code in {
      Space: false,
    }) {
    let bullet = new Projectile(x0, y0, 3, 2, 1500)
    projectileArray.push(bullet);
  }
  // console.log("boom")
});



var r_squared = 9230
for (var x = 0; x <= 100; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y <= 100; y++) {
    for (var z = 0; z <= 100; z++) {
      if (distance_squared(x, y, z) == r_squared) {
        // console.log(x, y, z)
        var cord = Coords_3D_To_2D(x, y, z)
        let bullet = new Projectile(x0 + cord.w, y0 + cord.h, 1, -Math.PI * 1.5, 500)
        projectileArray.push(bullet);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the distance `r`, what we should learn is to find all nonnegative integer solutions of `x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2` and then pick some solution randomly.

We can just enumerate `x` and `y` from 1 to r separately, and the check whether `r^2-x^2-y^2` is a perfect square number.

The complexity is `O(r^2)`

Comment: the thing is I can't check on r coordinates inside searchPoint function, only distance

Comment: Sorry, I did't read statement carefully before.
  And I haven't got the stuck point ? Could you make some more desciption?

Comment: I think the arr.length() of each element in `closePoints` must be 1?
 Because consider function dis_to_r(x,y,z)=(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0^2)
 for fixed y and z, we will have only one x to minimize dis_to_r(x,y,z)

Comment: And some other Idea ~
 An assumption is that you can query distance for (0,0,distance), (0,distance,0), (distance,0,0)
 just like 2-d version of this problem, you can query (0,distance), (distance,0) to find the postion of random point. right?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).